# Determine the distribution of the random variable $X_1+X_2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> $X_n= \begin{pmatrix}
> -1 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ with $p =  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2n} & 1-\frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{2n} \end{pmatrix}$ is a discrete random
>   variable. It's known that $E(X_n)=0$ and $Var(X_n)=\frac{1}{n}$ and
>   $X_n$ converges to zero.
>
> Determine the distribution of the random variable $X_1+X_2$

Edit: Here are all possibilities and their sum equals to $1$:

1.) $P(X_1=-1) \cdot P(X_2=0) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$

2.) $P(X_1=-1) \cdot P(X_2=1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8}$

3.) $P(X_1=-1) \cdot P(X_2=-1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8}$

4.) $P(X_1=1) \cdot P(X_2=1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8}$

5.) $P(X_1=1) \cdot P(X_2=0) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$

6.) $P(X_1=0) \cdot P(X_2=0) = 0 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 0$

7.) $P(X_1=0) \cdot P(X_2=-1) = 0 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = 0$

8.) $P(X_1=1) \cdot P(X_2=-1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8}$

9.) $P(X_1=0) \cdot P(X_2=1) = 0 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = 0$

$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}+0+0+\frac{1}{8}+0=1$

But how does the distribution function need to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are given that for any $n$ the random variable $X_n$ takes values $-1$, $0$ and $1$ with probabilities $\frac1{2n}$, $1-\frac1n$ and $\frac1{2n}$ respectively. 
So for $n=1$
$$
\mathbb P(X_1 = -1) = \mathbb P(X_1=1) = \frac12, \quad \mathbb P(X_1 = 0) = 1-\frac11=0.
$$
And for $n=2$ 
$$
\mathbb P(X_2 = -1) = \mathbb P(X_2=1) = \frac14, \quad \mathbb P(X_2 = 0) = 1-\frac12=\frac12.
$$
If it is not given joint distribution of $X_1$, $X_2$, it is impossible to find distribution of their sum. If it is supposed that these variables are independent, then $X_1+X_2$ can take values $-1+(-1)$, $-1+0$, $-1+1$ and so on, and the probabilities of these values can be found directly: 
$$
\mathbb P(X_1+X_2=-2) = \mathbb P(X_1=-1,X_2=-1) = \mathbb P(X_1=-1)\mathbb P(X_2=-1).
$$
Write all possible values and calculate all probabilities. Check whether sum of probabilities equals to one.

Comment: Thank you! I have written each possibility (I edited my question and write each possibility there) and if you take the sum of each probability you really get $1$ as result. But I don't know how to write the distribution function for this now?

Comment: First of all: you did not found the distribution of $X_1+X_2$ yet. Look at each variant and indicate what value of the sum is attained in this case. After that write probability mass function $\mathbb P(X_1+X_2=-2)=...$, $\mathbb P(X_1+X_2=-1) = ...$ and so on.
Second, you are asked to find distribution. Discrete distribution is described not only be CDF. First of all, a discrete distribution is determined by a set of values and their probabilities, i.e. PMF. If however you need to find CDF, look here: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter3/3_2_1_cdf.php

Comment: Misprint: "described not only **by** CDF"